# Can we create partition with data in it

Tags: partitioning

I want to create a new partition in my HD, but already I am having some data's on my disk. so how to create a new partition without affecting my data

Comment: Do you have room to create a partition?

Comment: can you clear this up for me? do you want one new partition or do you want two partitons, one old one with the data and a empty new one?

Comment: I am having HD with no partition, but now I want to create a partition without losing my data.

Comment: resize the single partition will create unallocated space.From that you can be able to create new partition without affecting the data.

Comment: @AvinashRaj can you elaborate

Comment: A HD "with no partition" but "data on it"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use GParted  to resize your partition and creating new partition without loss of data.
Use this tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Answer (score 0):

Yes,resize the single partition will create unallocated space.From that you can be able to create new partition without affecting the data.

- Boot ubuntu live disk.And then install gparted.Run the below commands on terminal to install gparted on your live-disk.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Open gparted,then right click on the partition you want to resize and select Resize/Move.Free up the space you want from that parition to create new partition.
- After that,an unallocated space exists below the partition.
- Then rightclick on the unallocated space and create new partition.